# clearer jquery textbox change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

my apologies to ask this question as there may e answers already existing just that the weren't clear enough to me. What is the best way to apply jquery change event on an html texbox control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below sample code.

<input type="text" class="common" />

<input type="text" class="common" />

<input type="text" class="common" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("input.common[type='text']").change(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        alert(value);
     });
 });
```

</script>

Comment: i have actually tried this but its not working for me, my code goes as follows $(.txt).change(function(){ alert('done') });

Comment: was not realy aware of the bind option as i am a beginner but ama try i out just now

Comment: i saw the demo and it works fine but can this also work in a case of textbox arrays when they share a class  name? how do you then copy the value of the changed text ox and paste in the other textoxes sharing the class?

Comment: what is your exact requirement?

Comment: i have created an array of textboxes at run time and added a class name to them using jquery...i now want to populate the values of these text boxes with the same value in case any of then has been changed, i want to use the class common class name to detect whether any memer of the class value has changed and alter the values of the rest with the same values as the one in the altered text box.

Comment: hey, i managed to achieve this task just as  you said i your answer, works well now, thank you @Deepu

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean textarea? Something like this:

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function() {
    //Do stuff
    console.log('Do something smart here!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On modern browsers, use oninput event:

```
$('textarea').on('input',function(event){
   alert(this.value);
});
```